# Redux: Cannot read property 'getState' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, redux, react-redux

currently I am learning Redux to create a simple todo app with React. This is how I have done

this is my reducer and store:

`/redux/todo.js`

```
const initialState = {
  items: []
};

const ADD_TODO = "ADD_TODO";

export const addTodo = (text) => ({
  type: ADD_TODO,
  payload: text
});

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TODO":
      return {
        ...state,
        items: [...state.items, action.payload]
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

`/redux/store.js`

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";

import todoReducer from "./todo";

const reducer = combineReducers({
  todo: todoReducer
});

export default createStore(reducer);
```

this is my component to map with redux:

`/components/TodoApp.js`

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function TodoApp({ todos, addTodo }) {
  const [text, setText] = useState("");

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        value={text}
        onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          addTodo(text);
        }}
      >
        Add
      </button>
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li>{todo}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is how I bind the store with the UI:

`/bindings/TodoApp.js`

```
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import TodoApp from "../components/TodoApp";
import { addTodo } from "../redux/todo";

const mapStateProps = (state) => {
  return {
    todos: state.todo.items
  };
};

const mapActionsToProps = {
  addTodo
};

export default connect(mapStateProps, mapActionsToProps)(TodoApp);
```

Then I import it in the root component:

`App.js`

```
import "./styles.css";
import TodoApp from "./bindings/TodoApp";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <TodoApp />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`

And finally, I add  of Redux to index file:

`index.js`

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { store } from "./redux/store";
import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StrictMode>
      <App />
    </StrictMode>
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
);
```

And this is the error I got:

[image]

Please help me to deal with it, thank you so much, if it is possible, please modify the code in this codesandbox link [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/redux-9-react-redux-7f9kv?file=/src/index.js:245-334)

Once again, thank you so much and have a good day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I see the codesandobx, the saw the error -

```
TypeError
store is undefined
```

I think you can just remove "{" brackets from "store" at 4th line of index.js since the `store` is the default import of store.js file and not the named import